# "event.returnValue = false" not registering in IE

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener, preventdefault, buttonclick

code:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16952797/webdev/uppg1/kontakt.html
(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16952797/webdev/uppg1/kontakt.js)
http://jsfiddle.net/mptA5/

relevant sections of code:

```
function addEvent(element, eventType, theFunction, capture)
{
    if(element.addEventListener)
    {
        element.addEventListener(eventType, theFunction, capture);
    } 
    else if(element.attachEvent)
    {
       element.attachEvent( "on" + eventType, theFunction);
    }
}

function validateInput(form)
{
switch(form)
{
    case "other":
        if (document.getElementById("textareaOtherComment").value == "")
        {
            alert("Vänligen fyll i kommentarfältet!");
            return false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("inputEmail").value == "")
        {
            alert("Vänligen fyll i mejlfältet!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;                                                    // NOTE: breaks aren't necessary after return statements
    case "sugg":
        if (document.getElementById("selectSuggestion").selectedIndex == 0)
        {
            alert("Vänligen välj en förslagskategori!");
            return false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("textareaSuggestionComment").value == "")
        {
            alert("Vänligen fyll i kommentarfältet!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;            
    default:
        return false;
}
}

function preventDefaultAction(event)
{
    if (event.preventDefault)
{
        event.preventDefault();
}
    else if (event.returnValue)
{
        event.returnValue = false;
}
}

function preventDefaultEvents()
{
    addEvent(document.getElementById("btnOtherSubmit"), "click", preventDefaultAction, false);
    addEvent(document.getElementById("btnBugSubmit"), "click", preventDefaultAction, false);
}

function addEventListeners()
{
.
.
.
    addEvent(document.getElementById("btnOtherSubmit"), "click", function(){submitForm("other");}, false);
.
.
.
    addEvent(document.getElementById("btnSuggestionSubmit"), "click", function(){submitForm("sugg");}, false);
.
.
.
}

function init()
{
.
.
.
    preventDefaultEvents();
    addEventListeners();
}
```

context: My "suggestion" (Lämna ett förslag) and "other" (övrigt) forms work as intended in chrome(W3C-browsers), but in IE (tested with IE8) the "other" form gets submitted on buttonclick even though the input didn't pass the validation process...
I've debugged the "suggestion" form and the "other" form in IE's F12 developer tools, it seems that upon buttonclick, the "other" form enters the preventDefaultAction function while the "suggestion" form doesn't upon failed validation.

Answer (score 1):

preventDefaultAction code should be inside validateInput function. In `default:` section, instead of `return false;`

Simple `return false;` doesn't prevent default browser action, if event handler was attached using AddEventListener()/attachEvent()

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the HTML document:

```
<input id=btnOtherSubmit class="buttons imagify buttonsSubmit btnSubmit" type=submit value=Skicka></div>
```

This error caused the submit() function of the form to fire without validating.

Line 52 is now changed to the following:

```
<div id=btnOtherSubmit class="buttons imagify buttonsSubmit">Skicka</div>
```